# how do i access C array float values from lldb python API

Tags: python, c, lldb

I am new using [python scripting in lldb](http://lldb.llvm.org/scripting.html#accessing-variables). I am debugging C code.

I want to copy the content of a C array of floats into a python variable in an lldb script. The ultimate goal goal is to plot the content array as is done [here](https://www.codeproject.com/articles/669606/analyzing-c-cplusplus-matrix-in-the-gdb-debugger-w) with gdb and python.

The C array in the program i'm debugging is declared as `float* buffer;`

In lldb python script if I do: `buf = lldb.frame.FindVariable ("buffer")` buf only contains the non dereferrenced pointer "buffer'" (the address of the array).

How do I access the actual values of the array (derefferenced) and copy them into a python variable? gdb has [gdb_numpy.to_array](https://www.codeproject.com/articles/669606/analyzing-c-cplusplus-matrix-in-the-gdb-debugger-w). I looked at [SBValue.h](https://llvm.org/svn/llvm-project/lldb/trunk/include/lldb/API/SBValue.h) and tried GetChildAtIndex method but with no luck.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Actually:

`x[i]=  float(buf.GetChildAtIndex(i,1,1).GetValue())`

Returns value of buf at index i

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that a float * isn't an array, it is a pointer to a float.  It might point to a contiguously allocated array of floats, or a single one, lldb can't tell.

So the SBValue for it is not going to be an array of N children, where N is the number of elements you've allocated for the array.  It will have a value - the pointer value - and one child - the value the pointer points at.

However, it is pretty simple to walk a contiguous array with the Python API:

Get your pointer:

```
>>> float_ptr = lldb.frame.FindVariable("float_ptr")
```

For convenience, store the type of the elements:

```
>>> float_type = float_ptr.GetType().GetPointeeType()
```

Now walk the array printing out elements (I made 10 floats for this example):

```
>>> for i in range (0,9):
...     offset = float_ptr.GetValueAsUnsigned() + i * float_type.GetByteSize()
...     val = lldb.target.CreateValueFromAddress("temp", lldb.SBAddress(offset, lldb.target), float_type)
...     print val
... 
(float) temp = 1
(float) temp = 2
(float) temp = 3
(float) temp = 4
(float) temp = 5
(float) temp = 6
(float) temp = 7
(float) temp = 8
(float) temp = 9
```

Answer (score 0):

@JimIngham's answer is excellent. The below example illustrates some other helpful commands and Jim's answer. The goal is to highlight how you can deal with a C array that decayed into a pointer.

```
void foo_void ( float *input )
{
    printf("Pointer: %p.\n", input); <-- breakpoint here
}

int main ( void ) {

    float tiny_array[4];
    tiny_array[0] = 1.0;
    tiny_array[1] = 2.0;
    tiny_array[2] = 3.0;
    tiny_array[3] = 4.0;


    foo_void ( tiny_array );
    return 0;
}
```

`LLDB-Python` instructions:

```
(lldb) fr v -L
0x00007ffeefbff4c8: (float *) input = 0x00007ffeefbff4f0

(lldb) script
Python Interactive Interpreter. To exit, type 'quit()', 'exit()'.

>>> ptr = lldb.frame.FindVariable('input')

>>> print(ptr.GetValue())
0x00007ffeefbff4f0

>>> ptr_type = ptr.GetType().GetPointeeType()

>>> print(ptr_type)
float

>>> ptr_size_type = ptr_type.GetByteSize()

>>> print(ptr_size_type)
4


>>> for i in range (0, 4):
...     offset = ptr.GetValueAsUnsigned() + i * ptr_size_type
...     val = lldb.target.CreateValueFromAddress("temp", lldb.SBAddress(offset, lldb.target), ptr_type)
...     print(offset, val.GetValue())
... 
(140732920755440, '1')
(140732920755444, '2')
(140732920755448, '3')
(140732920755452, '4')
```

Answer (score 0):

There is the **lldb.frame.EvaluateExpression** method. It allow simplify a script:

```
(lldb) script 
Python Interactive Interpreter. To exit, type 'quit()', 'exit()'.

>>> for i in range (0, 4):
...     print(lldb.frame.EvaluateExpression('input[%d]' % i).GetValue()) 
...
```